# Three refrigerators not cooling within 24 hours of being plugged in

Tags: refrigerator

I have an outbuilding where I have had a refrigerator for several years.

This spring, I added a second refrigerator in a different room of the outbuilding. Both were running and cooling when I left for the day.

The next day I arrived, and neither was cooling (lights work but no sounds, no sign the compressor was even running.) I thought it must have been a power surge or something to kill them both at the same time, but the main house had no problems with their appliances and hadn’t noted any power surge or flickering lights.

This week, I finally picked up a used fridge for free. Plugged it in, compressor kicked on, it started cooling. I left for the day.

The next morning same story - lights work, fridge is warm and compressor makes no sounds.

I tried unplugging and plugging back in and cleaned condenser coils but it still doesn’t cool.

It seems very unlikely that three fridges would suddenly die on their own. I’m convinced there’s something wrong with the electric in the building, but I have no idea what it is. Am I right that there’s an electrical problem? Any suggestions for where to start?

ETA:

There aren’t two fridges running at the same time. That was back in April when I plugged the second in, and the next morning both weren’t working. They’ve been unplugged and non-working since then. I plugged in just one “new” used fridge the other day and experienced the same thing (initially worked, not cooling the next day).

I have no idea about any of the electrical details of the building. It was used as a woodworking workshop by a professional carpenter with a lot of power equipment and additional lights for decades. There’s nothing in it drawing electricity currently except for some overhead lighting that gets turned on when I’m in there and otherwise is off.

The building is insulted but isn’t heated or cooled. I don’t think ambient temp is the issue, because they stopped working on late April when temps were moderate 60ish degrees.

I use the fridges to store seed, drinks and sometimes fresh flowers from my flower farm. All fridges are currently empty and unplugged because they’re not working. None of them will work when plugged in except for the interior light turning on when I open the door.

Comment: How far is outbuilding from power?  Does the outbuilding have enough power for two fridges?  The problem might be too much voltage drop.

Comment: we need more details.   what is the size of the electrical feed going to the outbuilding? Wire gauge?  Distance? Since it worked OK **before** you added the 2nd fridge, my best **GUESS** and it's only a guess w/o more info is that you significant voltage drop.  The way to test is to get a DMM (digital multi meter) and measure the voltage with both of the fridges up and running, if you can get them both to turn on at the same time.   Also, if practical, combine the contents into one of the fridges and and unplug the now empty one and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Is this outbuilding heated/cooled? If not, what is the ambient temperature near the refrigerator? Ordinary residential refrigerators are only designed to work properly in "normal" temperatures. Arguably they should still *try* to cool, but that may be a factor.

Comment: Get a Kill-a-Watt and monitor for voltage, to start with. A Lost Neutral on the feeder could cause the voltage to wander, and/or make on the fridge's operation depend on another cyclical 120V load being running.  E.G. the light you turn on when you go in there.  A Lost Hot could make it work when a 240V cyclical load is on (though that load would not function).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions of what could be wrong. I’ll check out your ideas.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica is right - a Kill-a-watt (or equivalent in other countries) is a very useful tool.  It's much safer than sticking multimeter probes into sockets, as well as being more informative and hands-free allowing you to switch loads on and off.  I'd also use a 3-lamp socket tester to indicate a different set of faults very clearly, even though they can be misleading so have to be read with care.